# Report viewer 2010 vertical header text not proper in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, reporting-services, cross-browser

I am using MS Reporting 2010.

In report, there is some vertical header text for which writing-mode property is used.

But when report is rendering in browser, *vertical text* doesn't render properly in Chrome and Firefox because these browsers are not supporting `writing-mode:bt-rl` css property. It works fine in IE.

Is there any solution or alternate to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not support vertical rendering of text in Chrome,Safari etc.
They have informed like it will be fixed as a part of 2008 R2 version. But it is not fixed even 2014 version released.